# Sparkfun Bluetooth Modem (RN41) Mode:entering pin

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, bluetooth

I'm trying to use the sparkfun bluetooth mate gold modem (microchip RN41) [link](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12580) in master mode to another BT modem in slave mode WITH pin authentication. However when I try to connect I receive the message TRYING followed by connect failed. Same situation when I try to connect with any device using pin authentication. 
My question is: how do I connect to another bluetooth mate that has pin authentication enabled? If it is at all possible. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried pairing the devices yet?

Comment: Yes, I can pair them without problem if I don't have pin authentication enabled. My issue Is I'm trying to connect to a device that has pin auth, but the RN41 never prompts me to input such a pin